# How to ask and answer questions without getting downvoted

Tags: discussion, down-votes, asking-questions

All the questions and answers I've posted in the past have gotten down voted, including the one on this account. I have read the guides on how to use the site, but nothing I have tried has ever worked. I can't access the meta site to get help because I have never been smart enough to get to 5 rep. Please downvote if I should just stop trying to use the site's user features.

Comment: How on earth did this get 3 upvotes in one minute? This seems like vote manipulation.

Comment: You now have 11. Take it to Meta.

Comment: The OP mentions.. **"THIS ACCOUNT"** Understand something? @CameronWilliams

Comment: Man, if you guys think I'm sockpuppeting, I might as well give up using this site at all. I just want to ask math questions without being downvoted to oblivion. Hanlon's razor please.

Comment: @SubhadeepDey I did

Comment: Could you link to some of these questions? Without any details I am afraid we cannot say more than the general advice.

Comment: If all my questions are metaquestions, does that mean I'm in a catch-22?

Comment: Should I give up since I can't figure out how to ask questions?

Comment: Why can't I ask metaquestions before asking real questions?

Comment: You can always ask on [meta.se]

Comment: The eleven reputation was taken away from me. Don't know why.

Comment: @Joe The reputation was taken away likely because this question was migrated to the meta site.

Comment: @Joe Personally, I've seen a lot of people be mean to new users just because they haven't been on the site long enough to understand all the rules or because they really don't know how to approach the problem and just want some kind of help even if they don't have work. However, we can't help you ask better questions if you don't show us the questions people have downvoted.

Comment: @NobleMushtak  It wasn't taken away. The meta site did just not yet catch up.

Comment: Is it okay to ask questions that have been answered before? I feel like this teaches the search engine to deal with phrasing better.

Comment: Is there some kind of cushion for newbs? I feel like all my problems with this site boil down to my lack of experience with the search engine.

Comment: @Joe As it stands, nothing can be said beyond the boilerplate advice about how to ask. If you were to link to some of your poorly received questions, one could give some constructive *specific* advice; but if you're just asking a general question, a general thread has the answers.

Comment: @Joe If you ask questions that have been answered before, unless you add some kind of value to the question that was not there before, unfortunately, people will almost certainly down vote them because they are duplicates, which are not allowed on this site. Simply changing the phrasing is not enough.

Comment: @Joe Also, yes, the search engine can be not helpful sometimes. I recently asked a question and someone told me a day later that it was a duplicate of theirs, which was not suggested by Math StackExchange in the Related Questions.

Comment: Often when I ask questions, I can't figure out how to be specific. Only after I've read some answers can I zero in on what I was missing. Is this problematic?

Comment: @Joe Yes, it is. Vague questions are rarely constructive.

Comment: How do I translate math questions into text without loosing any of the meatspace context?

Comment: How did you figure out how to use this website?

Comment: @Joe What is "meatspace context?"

Comment: Irl I show you what my textbook says, compare notes. Draw abstracted pictures of the principles in question. Stuff like that.

Comment: Maybe the barrier to entry of this place is too high.

Comment: Welp, sorry for bugging you guys, clearly this was a waste of everyone's time.

Comment: @Joe You can use https://imgur.com/ to upload images to the Internet and then paste the link to the image in your question. Then, a user with enough reputation will edit your question so that the image can be embedded within your question. You can also use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to embed equations into questions.

Comment: Joe, as long as you refuse to link to the questions involved, it is a waste of time.

Comment: @Joe I really suggest that you stay on the site and try again with all these new tips. I don't think helping you was a waste of time. If one of your problems was trying to put your notes into your question, that can be fixed with imgur.com. Usually, people are willing to help others if they have some kind of work or image from a textbook, even if that work is a link to an image (although honestly, other times, unfortunately, people are mean to users who use images because it's not embedded into the question using MathJax).

Comment: @WillJagy Please consider that it's possible that the old questions Joe had were deleted, so Joe's not sharing them.

Comment: @NobleMushtak it still ought to be possible to give some specific information about their nature. You may consider the possibility this is just  not  a good faith post.

Comment: "You can use imgur.com to upload images to the Internet and then paste the link to the image in your question." This is genius. You are a genius. Keeping being excellent man. I think this is exactly what I needed.

Comment: @NobleMushtak Given the number of sudden upvotes on a post that should really not have received them, together with the absolute refusal to engage with comments asking for specifics, I'm a little skeptical about this person's intentions.

Comment: @Joe Go to the top of the page. Under your question text, it should say **(discussion)** and then under that, there are lots of buttons. One of those buttons should say "delete." Click that button and this thread will be deleted. I think you will still be able to view it and undelete the thread (I might be wrong about this), but only you and moderators will be able to see it.

Comment: @NobleMushtak There are upvoted answers, so the question cannot be deleted. Joe: Please use civil language here.

Comment: @T.Bongers Sorry, I didn't know about that.

Comment: Comments feature a $\otimes$ for deletion at the end, if you move your mouse over your comment.

Comment: @quid They gave us specific information by asking us specific questions like whether or not it was OK to ask duplicates or how to communicate textbook notes/pictures in questions. Also, arguably, I've asked questions in bad faith before in that I already knew the answer on the main site and usually, I answer my own questions myself. It doesn't matter whether or not this is a real or fake situation because it's a real issue and I know that Joe's not the new user with this problem. We need to deal with the barrier to entry that new users sometimes experience.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because does not seem to be a question meant in good faith

Comment: All right thanks for the help mushtak.

Comment: @Joe No problem! I'm glad I could help you, even if a lot of people don't believe this is a real issue. I wish you the best of luck on this site!

Comment: Wouldn't let me delete this. I tagged it for moderation to do so.

Comment: @NobleMushtak they never answered my question for the earlier questions.

Comment: @quid Think of this from the perspective of a frustrated student. Except for the initial suspicions of gang-upvoting, Joe wasn't really directly answering any of our questions for the first 20 minutes of his commenting but was instead asking his own frustrated questions about how to use the site. It's reasonable that he didn't respond to everything, especially because some people were being suspicious of him (which Joe likely interpreted as rude), because he wanted to get his questions out.

Comment: @quid Also, you never answered my point that it doesn't matter if this question is in bad faith. Does that mean you're in bad faith? (NOTE: I don't think you're in bad faith.) Unfortunately, I need to leave now, but I'd just like everyone to consider the perspective of someone who's frustrated with the site, because from my perspective, as a high schooler that is around high schoolers 35-40 hours a week for 10 months a year, this is basically the reaction to what seems to them as a bunch of teachers demanding too much from them when they need help that I would expect.

Comment: @NobleMushtak there is by now a strain of 30+ comments, mostly worthless. It does matter. That's all. I will not add one more.

Answer (score 8):

Roughly an up vote corresponds to an encouragement by some other user, a down vote to a discouragement.

My personal policy:

- down votes for obvious b$\star$llsh$\star$t
- down votes if the poster was far too lazy and tries to offload his work for free
- down votes if answers are wrong (*) and discussion in the comments has beared no fruit
- no down votes if the poster has no clue but seems honest
- up votes if something was useful
- up votes if something was really cool or otherwise impressive
- up votes if I want to encourage some folk to stay and keep trying

(*) I am only human and make mistakes too

Comment: How dare you to be only human and make mistakes???

Answer (score 5):

> Is it okay to ask questions that have been answered before? I feel like this teaches the search engine to deal with phrasing better.

If you ask questions that have been answered before, unless you add some kind of value to the question that was not there before, unfortunately, people will almost certainly down vote them because they are duplicates, which are not allowed on this site because we do not want the same discussion to be in the site on multiple questions. Simply changing the phrasing is not enough.

> Is there some kind of cushion for newbs? I feel like all my problems with this site boil down to my lack of experience with the search engine.

Unfortunately, no, there is not. People usually just expect new users to understand all of the rules and ask quality questions, even though most people aren't really taught how to ask quality questions in school and to many people, this sort of forum is new.

Also, the search engine can be a bit annoying because it often does not give me the question I want, even if I know it exists, so if you ask duplicate questions when you looked for questions of your type and could not find any, it is understandable, but unfortunately, it will still probably be marked as duplicate if people find a similar question, even if that's not your fault.

> Often when I ask questions, I can't figure out how to be specific. Only after I've read some answers can I zero in on what I was missing. Is this problematic?

If you have a specific problem but no specific work, try to be very specific with the problem as you can. People usually appreciate users who describe the question in-depth even if they do not show any work. However, people are usually critical of users who post a very short question with no work because they see these as low-quality where answers will only help the user answering that short question instead of fostering a quality question. However, this also isn't necessarily new users' fault because again, people aren't really taught how to ask good questions in school and many people are new to these types of math forums.

In short, just try to be as specific as possible and if you want some kind of hint to your question, but not a full answer, people might give you that hint even if your question is very short. I've seen many answerers leave very small hints on questions, even if the question is very short and those answerers later say that such questions don't deserve a full answer. I think you're more likely to get a useful hint if you ask for it politely even if you don't show any work, but if you're not specific, even if you try your best, unfortunately, you might not get an answer.